# SQL Server complex aggregate filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to optimize some queries that run against a large amount of data. I'll try simplifying the problem here. Let's start with an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
    [ProjectID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Index] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Voltage] [DECIMAL](18, 3) NOT NULL,
    [Current] [DECIMAL](18, 3) NOT NULL
)
```

And imagine we have the following data:

```
ProjectID   Index   Voltage     Current
---------------------------------------
1           1       2.3         3.4 
1           2       2.5         3.3
1           3       2.7         3.0
1           4       2.8         2.9
1           5       2.5         3.1
1           6       2.0         3.4
1           7       1.2         3.5
1           8       0.5         3.0
2           1       2.0         1.0
2           2       5.0         2.0
2           3       3.0         2.0
2           4       1.0         1.0
```

My goal is actually to do some aggregates between a starting point and an ending point ordered by the index column. When I mean starting and ending points, I mean, for example, start at the first row that has Voltage >= 2.5 and then continue on until I hit the last row that has Voltage >= 1.5

Here's an example query to illustrate:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        StartingTable.ProjectID,
        MIN(StartingTable.[Index]) StartingIndex,
        MIN(EndingTable.[Index]) - 1 EndingIndex
    FROM
        TestTable StartingTable
        JOIN TestTable EndingTable ON StartingTable.ProjectID = EndingTable.ProjectID
            AND EndingTable.[Index] > StartingTable.[Index]
    WHERE
        StartingTable.Voltage >= 2.5
        and EndingTable.Voltage <= 1.5
    GROUP BY
        StartingTable.ProjectID
)
SELECT
    TestTable.ProjectID,
    MAX(Voltage) MaxVoltage,
    StartingIndex,
    EndingIndex
FROM
    TestTable
    JOIN CTE ON TestTable.ProjectID = CTE.ProjectID
        AND TestTable.[Index] >= StartingIndex
        AND TestTable.[Index] <= EndingIndex
GROUP BY
    TestTable.ProjectID,
    StartingIndex,
    EndingIndex
```

And in the example, it should be returning:

```
ProjectID MaxVoltage StartingIndex EndingIndex
1         2.800      2             6
2         5.000      2             3
```

That works ok, but I really don't like joining TestTable twice in order to get starting and ending index. We're dealing with a table that I think may eventually end up with terabytes worth of data, so I think this is a poor choice. I just don't know what else to do.

I was thinking about some way to use windowed functions, but I'm not sure it's even possible. It's almost like I want to do this:

```
MAX(Voltage) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID ORDER BY [Index] ROWS BETWEEN Voltage >= 2.5 AND Voltage >= 1.5)
```

I haven't seen where anything like that's possible. I also came up with the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ProjectID,
        [Index],
        MAX(Voltage) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectId ORDER BY [Index] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) MaxVoltage
    FROM
        TestTable
)
SELECT
    TestTable.ProjectID,
    MAX(Voltage) MaxVoltage,
    MIN(TestTable.[Index]) StartingIndex,
    MAX(TestTable.[Index]) EndingIndex
FROM
    TestTable
    JOIN CTE ON TestTable.ProjectID = CTE.ProjectID
        AND TestTable.[Index] = CTE.[Index]
WHERE
    MaxVoltage >= 2.5
    AND Voltage >= 1.5
GROUP BY
    TestTable.ProjectID
```

I'm not sure that is much better. Are there any better alternatives than what I'm already trying?

Comment: How about, you try to create a unique key in your CTE (concate columns rather than just display separately) and then use 'IN' clause to get your output, instead of second join query.

Comment: @Wocugon - the problem with that is it's going to invalidate the use of an index, which on a table of any real size is immediately going to tank performance (it's not going to have a stored lookup key).  In general, you should avoid using _any_ function on a join/search column (including things like `CAST`) - save that for constants and small work tables (ie - creating a range table of Mondays from a calendar table is usually fine, because the resulting set is small and pulled into memory anyways).

Comment: @Dan - If your project runs are short, the self join isn't likely to cause as many problems, because the cartesian join will have fewer rows (although your query should be tweaked to help with that).  As the runs get larger, things get much worse.  Question, though: what happens if a run "restarts"?  If, after falling below 1.5 volts it gets back over 2.5 volts, what do you want to happen?

Comment: I did consider whether the run would restart, but I'm pretty sure it won't.

Comment: Also; as a matter of "correctness", I tend to assume positive values should always be queried upper-bound exclusive.  The `Voltage` column is `DECIMAL(18,3)` - what happens with the value `1.51`?  `1.501`?  `1.5001`?  That is, I operate under the assumption that the "include value bound" _starts_ at `1.5` - and the "exclude value bound" is "less than `1.5` ".  Which is the way I wrote my query, and how your second attempt works (but not @dnoeth's second query or your first attempt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tt.ProjectID, 
       MAX(tt.Voltage) AS MaxVoltage,
       x.StartIndex,
       MAX(tt.[Index]) AS EndIndex
FROM TestTable AS tt
JOIN 
(  
    SELECT ProjectID, 
           MIN([Index]) AS StartIndex
    FROM TestTable
    WHERE Voltage >= 2.5
    GROUP BY ProjectID 
) AS x ON tt.ProjectID = x.ProjectID 
WHERE tt.Voltage >= 1.5 
  AND tt.[Index] >= x.StartIndex
GROUP BY tt.ProjectID, x.StartIndex
```

See the full test here: https://rextester.com/BCVL10968

Comment: That does seem to be a bit faster. I think I'll go with it. Thanks.

Comment: If your table is really really large, I guess we can create that nested SELECT statement as a temp table and put index on the ProjectID column. But I'd say the benefit would only be obvious when your table is so large that event that nested statement is too large to be in-memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply *conditional aggregation* if the voltage never goes above 2.5, then below 1.5 and then increases above 1.5 again:

```
SELECT
   ProjectID,
   max(Voltage) as MaxVoltage,
   MIN(case when Voltage >= 2.5 then [index] end) AS StartingIndex,
   MAX(case when Voltage >= 1.5 then [index] end) AS EndingIndex
FROM TestTable
group by ProjectID
having MAX(Voltage) >= 2.5 -- to filter group which never reached 2.5
```

See [rextester fiddle](https://rextester.com/BUIE12609)

Edit:

If your Voltage has repeated groups between 2.5 and 1.5 query #2 by @Clockwork-Muse will work fine as long as there's no gap in the `[index]` columns, otherwise it will split one result row into two groups. If you want to ignore gaps following Select will return the expected result:

```
with cte as 
(
   SELECT
      ProjectID,
      [Index],
      Voltage,
      max(case when Voltage < 1.5 then [Index] end)
      over (partition by ProjectID
            order by [Index]
            rows unbounded preceding) AS grp -- same value for a range of rows >= 1.5
   FROM TestTable
 )
select
   ProjectID,
   max(Voltage) as MaxVoltage,
   MIN(case when Voltage >= 2.5 then [index] end) AS StartingIndex,
   MAX([index]) AS EndingIndex
from cte
where Voltage >=1.5
group by ProjectID, grp
having MAX(Voltage) >= 2.5 -- to filter group which never reached 2.5
order by ProjectID, grp
;
```

This groups contiguous rows with `Voltage >= 1.5` and starts a new group whenever it drops below 1.5, see Clockwork-Muse's modified [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=868482a9432c8639467489e377c17587)

Comment: @Dan . . . This seems like a much better answer than the one you accepted.

Comment: For your second query, the grouping condition will put `1.5`-valued rows into the wrong group (and doesn't match the comment) - the bound should probably be exclusive (`CASE WHEN Voltage < 1.5`)... although the OP's original attempts went both ways.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Yep, thanks, either this or the 2nd one should be `Voltage < 1.5`

Answer (score 0):

If, as in your example dataset, voltages only decrease after hitting 1.5 volts (and never repeat), we can cheat via use of a conditional aggregate:

```
SELECT [ProjectID], MAX([Voltage]) AS MaxVoltage, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN [Voltage] >= 2.5 THEN [Index] END) AS [StartingIndex],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Voltage] >= 1.5 THEN [Index] END) AS [EndingIndex]
FROM [dbo].[TestTable]
WHERE [Voltage] >= 1.5
GROUP BY [ProjectId]
HAVING MAX([Voltage]) >= 2.5
```

<kbd>[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6956cfb049df17fae3d82c9453566298)</kbd>
Which yields the requested:

```
ProjectID | MaxVoltage | StartingIndex | EndingIndex
--------: | :--------- | ------------: | ----------:
        1 | 2.800      |             2 |           6
        2 | 5.000      |             2 |           3
```

---

If, on the other hand, we need to be wary of restarts, things get more complicated, and we need to turn it into a variation on a [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) solution:

```
SELECT [ProjectID], MAX([Voltage]) AS [MaxVoltage],
       MIN(CASE WHEN [Voltage] >= 2.5 THEN [Index] END) AS [StartingIndex],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Voltage] >= 1.5 THEN [Index] END) AS [EndingIndex]
FROM (SELECT [ProjectId], [Index], [Voltage], 
             [Index] - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ProjectID] ORDER BY [Index]) AS [VoltageRun]
      FROM [dbo].[TestTable]       
      WHERE [Voltage] >= 1.5) [TestTable]
GROUP BY [ProjectID], [VoltageRun]
HAVING MAX([Voltage]) >= 2.5
ORDER BY [ProjectID], [VoltageRun]
```

<kbd>[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=088c62cd7186123c68cc143e594beb58)</kbd>

This works because your table handily stores the (hopefully gapless) `[Index]` column.  By only selecting rows that are valid *at all* (`>= 1.5`), the `ROW_NUMBER()` subtraction gains us a "grouping column" - before the aggregation, the result set looks like this:

```
ProjectId | Index | Voltage | VoltageRun
--------: | ----: | :------ | :---------
        1 |     1 | 2.300   | 0         
        1 |     2 | 2.500   | 0         
        1 |     3 | 2.700   | 0         
        1 |     4 | 2.800   | 0         
        1 |     5 | 2.500   | 0         
        1 |     6 | 2.000   | 0         
        1 |     9 | 2.300   | 2         
        1 |    10 | 2.500   | 2         
        1 |    11 | 2.700   | 2         
        1 |    12 | 2.800   | 2         
        1 |    13 | 2.500   | 2         
        1 |    14 | 2.000   | 2         
        2 |     1 | 2.000   | 0         
        2 |     2 | 5.000   | 0         
        2 |     3 | 3.000   | 0
```

(The test data for `[ProjectID]=1` has been repeated)

After that, we just need to include the grouping column as an extra qualifier in the original query.
(Note that this type of query is one of the few times it makes sense to leave the grouping column out of the `SELECT` list)

Comment: I do have some voltage values that are kind of "floating" around the 2.5 and 1.5 values. So, technically I guess there are "restarts". However, I did something a little differently to get past it. But thanks for the suggestion. I may revisit your solution if mine isn't performing well enough.